# How can Jaspersoft Bean Datasource be deployed in Jasper Server?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver, jaspersoft-studio

Can anyone please help me with the step by step procedures to add a Bean DataSource (collection of beans) in the Jaspersoft Server? Is there a straightforward process of just pushing the jarfile so the server could recognize it?

here are the steps i did (simplified names)

**In Studio project**

- Create a Java Bean called **Person** containing fields and getter/setters
- Create a simple Java Class which connects to database named **com.company.test.PersonFactory**, it has a method **generator()** which returns a **List**, it uses simple jdbc calls, both classes are in my Jasper project
- Created a Data Adaptor called **testBean** and entered **com.company.test.PersonFactory** as the Factory Class and generator as the static method in the Factory.
- Create a new jasper report (**testReport1**) and use the Data Adapter **testBean**, clicked the Java Bean tab, enter **Person** as the classname, add all fields, verified data preview, and save

**In Repository Explorer**

- Create a new Data Source > Data Source Bean, enter **bean1** as name and id
- At the Bean Name and Bean method page, Select import from Jaspersoft Studio and select **testBean**, click finish

**In Studio project**

- After verifying that data preview in Jaspersoft Studio is working, publish the report in the Jasper Server
- Select the **bean1** datasource and publish

**In Jaspersoft Server**

run the report testReport1

**get the error**

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'com.company.test.PersonFactory' is defined at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:575)
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1111)
>   at
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:276)
>   at 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
>   at 
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1119)
>   at 
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.BeanReportDataSourceServiceFactory.createService(BeanReportDataSourceServiceFactory.java:76)
>   at  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   ....

Can anyone help me do the simplest steps on how the Beans and Factory would be recognized in the Jaspersoft Server?

Thanks

Comment: You need to follow the instructions in chapter "Bean Data Sources" from the "JasperReports Server Admin Guide". This means you need to deploy a JAR with your classes in the WEB-INF/lib of the server and edit some Spring files to declare you bean data source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue a week after my initial question. I just wanted to share the answer:

The jaspersoft Bean DataSource should be accessed through a class which implements **ReportDataSourceService**.

Then, it should have a private variable

```
private JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource;
```

also, you need to Override 2 methods

```
@Override
public void closeConnection() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void setReportParameterValues(Map parameterMap) {
    parameterMap.put(JRParameter.REPORT_DATA_SOURCE, dataSource);

}
```

Then from the Jasper server, you need to define the factory class which calls the constructor of the  **ReportDataSourceService** implemented class you created whicle returning a ReportDataSourceService type